# Quickly kill processes containing word

Tags: process, osx, kill

```
$ ps aux | grep ruby
user              1565   3.7  0.1  4307464  17696 s000  S+    7:31AM   0:00.61 /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby bin/rails c
user              1579   0.0  0.0  4268020    788 s001  S+    7:31AM   0:00.00 grep ruby
user              1489   0.0  0.0        0      0   ??  Z     7:29AM   0:00.00 (ruby)
```

How do I quickly kill all these processes?

What I tried:

```
kill -9 `ps aux | grep ruby`
```

My environment:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ uname -a
Darwin MacBook-Pro.local 18.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.0.0: Wed Aug 22 20:13:40 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4903.201.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$
```

Comment: [pkill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) might be the command you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Haxiel commented, my recommendation would be to use [pkill](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482996/quickly-kill-processes-containing-word#comment884464_482996):

```
pkill -9 ruby
```

Comment: `-9` is it required?

Comment: Nope; the OP gave that as the example that they wanted.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer. Mine works as well but yours is cleaner and less tedious. I'm aware of the `pkill` command but I use `kill` out of habit and didn't want to give misinformation as I didn't have a computer to test at the time.

Comment: I don't have an OSX system at hand, either, but I'm encouraged by the existence of the corresponding man page.

Comment: short n sweet !

Answer (score 1):

`kill $(ps aux | grep ruby | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs)`

`for p in $(ps aux | grep ruby | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'); do kill $p; done`

You can substitute `kill9` for `kill` if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I Tried with below command

```
ps -eaf | grep -i ruby| grep -iv 'grep'| awk '{print "kill -9" " " $2}'| sh
```

Comment: awk can grep as well as execute system commands, which would remove three of the pipeline commands

Comment: I Added  only awk method

Comment: ps -eaf | grep -i ssh| awk '$(NF-2) !~/grep/{print "kill -9" " " $2}'| sh